# value error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)Deep Neural Network - Application

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, valueerror

I wrote this function:

```
def two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):

    """
    Implements a two-layer neural network: LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->SIGMOID.
    
    Arguments:
    X -- input data, of shape (n_x, number of examples)
    Y -- true "label" vector (containing 1 if cat, 0 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
    layers_dims -- dimensions of the layers (n_x, n_h, n_y)
    num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
    print_cost -- If set to True, this will print the cost every 100 iterations 
    
    Returns:
    parameters -- a dictionary containing W1, W2, b1, and b2
    """
    
    np.random.seed(1)
    grads = {}
    costs = []                              # to keep track of the cost
    m = X.shape[1]                           # number of examples
    #(n_x, n_h, n_y) = layers_dims
    layers_dims=(n_x, n_h, n_y)
    # Initialize parameters dictionary, by calling one of the functions you'd previously implemented
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Get W1, b1, W2 and b2 from the dictionary parameters.
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    b1 = parameters["b1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    b2 = parameters["b2"]
    
    # Loop (gradient descent)

    for i in range(0, num_iterations):

        # Forward propagation: LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID. Inputs: "X, W1, b1, W2, b2". Output: "A1, cache1, A2, cache2".
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
        A1, cache1 = linear_activation_forward(X, W1, b1, activation="relu")
        A2, cache2 = linear_activation_forward(A1, W2, b2, activation="sigmoid")
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        
        # Compute cost
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        cost = compute_cost(A2, Y)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        
        # Initializing backward propagation
        dA2 = - (np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2))
        
        # Backward propagation. Inputs: "dA2, cache2, cache1". Outputs: "dA1, dW2, db2; also dA0 (not used), dW1, db1".
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
        dA1, dW2, db2 = linear_activation_backward(dA2, cache2, activation="sigmoid")
        dA0, dW1, db1 = linear_activation_backward(dA1, cache1, activation="relu")
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        
        # Set grads['dWl'] to dW1, grads['db1'] to db1, grads['dW2'] to dW2, grads['db2'] to db2
        grads['dW1'] = dW1
        grads['db1'] = db1
        grads['dW2'] = dW2
        grads['db2'] = db2
        
        # Update parameters.
        ### START CODE HERE ### (approx. 1 line of code)
        parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
        
        # Retrieve W1, b1, W2, b2 from parameters
        W1 = parameters["W1"]
        b1 = parameters["b1"]
        W2 = parameters["W2"]
        b2 = parameters["b2"]
        
        # Print the cost every 100 training example
        if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
            print("Cost after iteration {}: {}".format(i, np.squeeze(cost)))
        if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)
       
    # plot the cost

    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per hundreds)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
    plt.show()
    
    return parameters
```

and then

```
parameters, costs = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)

print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))

two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)
```

And then I received this error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 parameters, costs = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)
2
3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
4
5 two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Please help me.

Comment: Your function: `two_layer_model` return one parameter, why do you expect to get two parameters: `parameters, costs`?

Comment: That's true. I edited my function but I received this error:     IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-f9ec5304d38d> in <module>
      1 parameters, costs = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)
      2 
----> 3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
      4 
      5 two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: change this : from `parameters, costs = two_layer_model(...)` -> `parameters = two_layer_model(...)`

Comment: I did it but I received this error ,again.                                                 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-f471a45738cc> in <module>
      1 parameters = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)
      2 
----> 3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
      4 
      5 two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: OK, try this. in Your function write `return parameters , costs` instead of `return parameters`.

Comment: I edited my function and wrote return parameters , costs instead of return parameters. but I received this error: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-f9ec5304d38d> in <module>
      1 parameters, costs = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)
      2 
----> 3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
      4 
      5 two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct code from mhmd nojim

1- from public_tests import *
in the first cell in jupyter to imprt  public_tests

```
import time
import numpy as np
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from PIL import Image
from  scipy import ndimage
from dnn_app_utils_v3 import *
from public_tests import *

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (5.0, 4.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

np.random.seed(1)
```

2- in def two_layer_model replace the following function

```
### GRADED FUNCTION: two_layer_model

def two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):

 
np.random.seed(1)
grads = {}
costs = []                              # to keep track of the cost
m = X.shape[1]                           # number of examples
(n_x, n_h, n_y) = layers_dims

# Initialize parameters dictionary, by calling one of the functions you'd previously implemented
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)

# YOUR CODE ENDS HERE

# Get W1, b1, W2 and b2 from the dictionary parameters.
W1 = parameters["W1"]
b1 = parameters["b1"]
W2 = parameters["W2"]
b2 = parameters["b2"]

# Loop (gradient descent)

for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID. Inputs: "X, W1, b1, W2, b2". Output: "A1, cache1, A2, cache2".
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A1, cache1 = linear_activation_forward(X, W1, b1, activation = 'relu')
    A2, cache2 = linear_activation_forward(A1, W2, b2, activation = 'sigmoid')
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
    
    # Compute cost
    #(≈ 1 line of code)
    # cost = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    cost = compute_cost(A2, Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Initializing backward propagation
    dA2 = - (np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2))
    
    # Backward propagation. Inputs: "dA2, cache2, cache1". Outputs: "dA1, dW2, db2; also dA0 (not used), dW1, db1".
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dA1, dW2, db2 = linear_activation_backward(dA2, cache2, activation = 'sigmoid')
    dA0, dW1, db1 = linear_activation_backward(dA1, cache1, activation = 'relu')
    ### END CODE HERE ###
    
    # Set grads['dWl'] to dW1, grads['db1'] to db1, grads['dW2'] to dW2, grads['db2'] to db2
    grads['dW1'] = dW1
    grads['db1'] = db1
    grads['dW2'] = dW2
    grads['db2'] = db2
    
    # Update parameters.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (approx. 1 line of code)
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE

    # Retrieve W1, b1, W2, b2 from parameters
    W1 = parameters["W1"]
    b1 = parameters["b1"]
    W2 = parameters["W2"]
    b2 = parameters["b2"]
    
    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0 or i == num_iterations - 1:
        print("Cost after iteration {}: {}".format(i, np.squeeze(cost)))
    if i % 100 == 0 or i == num_iterations:
        costs.append(cost)
   

return parameters , costs
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function two_layer_model, you return only the `parameters`.
If you replace the line `return parameters` with `return parameters, costs` then your code will work

Comment: That's true. I edited my function and wrote return parameters , costs instead of return parameters. but I received this error: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-f9ec5304d38d> in <module>
      1 parameters, costs = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2, print_cost=False)
      2 
----> 3 print("Cost after first iteration: " + str(costs[0]))
      4 
      5 two_layer_model_test(two_layer_model)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: When I changed this : from parameters, costs = two_layer_model(...) -> parameters = two_layer_model(...)                I received this error, again:                                                                   change this : from parameters, costs = two_layer_model(...) -> parameters = two_layer_model(...)

Comment: The problem is that when you try to print `costs[0]`, the first element of costs is accessed. But `costs` is an empty list with no elements, so it gives an IndexError

Comment: In the function two_layer_model, you have written `if print_cost and i % 100 == 0: costs.append(cost)`. This means that the cost is only added to costs every 100 times the loop happens! To stop this happening replace that with just `costs.append(cost)`

Comment: Also keep it as `return parameters, costs` and `parameters, costs = ...`